# How to gracefully terminate a process executed within a Task in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

To explain my situation simply, I need to run a PowerShell script in a task in order to retrieve its standard output asynchronously.

The task is created by pressing a "run" button and I'd like to stop it with another "stop" button.

My function for creating the task, starting the process and retrieving the standard output:

```
public async Task ExecuteScriptAsync(string scriptPath)
    {
        if (_process != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        Label = "waiting...";

        _task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(scriptPath);
            _process = new Process();
            var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = $"/c chcp 65001 > nul && powershell.exe -File script_1.ps1",
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
            };
            _process.StartInfo = psi;
            _process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            _process.OutputDataReceived += (s, args) =>
            {
                var output = args.Data;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(output))
                {
                    outputBuilder.AppendLine(output);
                    UpdateLabel(outputBuilder.ToString());
                }
            };

            _process.ErrorDataReceived += (s, args) =>
            {
                var error = args.Data;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
                {
                    errorBuilder.AppendLine(error);
                    UpdateLabel(errorBuilder.ToString());
                }
            };

            _process.Start();
            _process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            _process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        });

        _process = null;
    }
```

I've tried that, except that it doesn't stop _process and the main thread pauses while the thread executes...

```
public async Task StopExecuteScriptAsync()
{
    if (_task == null || _process == null) return;

    _process.Kill();
    _process.WaitForExit();

    // Réinitialiser les valeurs
    _task.Dispose();
    _task = null;
    _process = null;
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting `_process` to null in the `ExecuteScriptAsync` method?

Comment: When using Standard Output the OS closes the Standard Output stream so the WaitForExit recognizes the process ends.  You code is not closing the Standard Output.  Either close the Standard Output or change code to wait for an end character.

Comment: @PMF it's a mistake 

Comment: @jdweng yup, i have made a mistake with my copy/paste to try and find a solution :c

But it pisses me off, I really don't see how I can stop the process (and not the standard output).

Comment: Why is `StopExecuteScriptAsync` returning a task without doing anything asynchronous or task-related?

Comment: Use [cancellationToken](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=net-7.0)

Comment: You can't stop another process gracefully, from any language, unless that process has some feature/API that allows this. CancellationToken is a local class, only available in .NET. It's not part of the OS and can't be passed to other processes. You can use cross-process synchronization primitives like a Semaphore or Mutex.

Comment: @Max you can't pass a CancellationToken to another process

Comment: BTW the entire commandline is wrong `FileName = "cmd.exe",` isn't needed *at all* and only makes things a lot harder. You aren't even using the CMD shell but PowerShell. At the very least you should be using `pwsh.exe` instead of `cmd.exe` BUT you can also host Powershell inside your own application with `PowerShell.Create`, as [this article shows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.3).

Comment: I agree, you shouldn't be going out to `cmd` to go out to `powershell`, just run PS inside your app using `Powershell.Create`